# React-Native Realm database change defaultPath

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I'm developing a TrainingPlan React-Native App.

I want to store the data in Realm database.
When I create the default database file, it works great:

```
let realm=new Realm({path:'training.realm});
realm.write(() => {
realm.create('Training', { type: 'group',  members: 12, });
});
```

It creates the training.realm in this path and works well (I/O):   /data/data/com.realmtmp/files/training.realm

If I want to change tha path, where to create the training.realm file, I'm using this:

```
let realm=new Realm({path:'/storage/emulated/0/training.realm'});
realm.write(() => {
realm.create('Training', { type: 'group',  members: 12, });
});
```

This creates the file, but shows "Error Read-only file system".
In this path I can create folders, copy files to there.

Why does this show read-only? 
(Same error on Android Studio AVD and real USB connected mobile phone.)

Regards,
 Imre

Comment: Because you have not acquired the runtime permission to write to external storage.

Comment: Thanks, how could I do that?

Comment: Seems to be  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, but the error still exists.

Comment: I can only create realm in this path: /data/data/com.realmproject/...

Everywhere else it says no read-write permission or read-only filesystem.

Comment: Please join this related issue to fix this bug: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1760